Web Push notification not sending the first time
I've been experimenting with web push notification by building a very simple pwa that sends me a notification every day. For some reason when I send a notification I get a successful result on my server, but the notification does not arrive to my browser/phone. Only when I send two notifications close after each other I receive two notifications. I have no idea how to fix/debug this issue. Do any of you have any insight or ideas?
I'm sending the push notifications using web-push the way they recommend it so I'm not doing anything special here.
Thanks!
